# ASP.NET ListBox Styling - Remove Borders and add Shading

Tags: asp.net, css, listbox, styling

So I'm having a heck of a time doing something that I think should be so simple.

I have an `<asp:ListBox />` element that I want to style, as I think the default looks horrendous, especially the border.

But very few attributes seem to take effect in CSS, most notably the border cannot be removed.

The caveat is that I need it to work in IE8 and IE7, not just other more modern browsers.

[This example site](http://obout.com/ListBox/aspnet_live_styles.aspx) has beautiful listbox elements, but I can't get anywhere close to them.

Any thoughts?

Heres the HTML:

```
<asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple" AutoPostBack="true"
    onselectedindexchanged="ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged" CssClass="myListBox" >
    <asp:ListItem>ITEM 1</asp:ListItem>  
    <asp:ListItem>ITEM 2</asp:ListItem>  
    <asp:ListItem>ITEM 3</asp:ListItem>  
    <asp:ListItem>ITEM 4</asp:ListItem>  
</asp:ListBox>
```

And the CSS:

```
.myListBox
{
    border-style:none;
    border-width:0px;
    border: none;
    font-size:12pt;
    font-family:Verdana;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your CSS class

```
CssClass="myListbox"
```

should be

```
CssClass="myListBox"
```

Then you can apply styles on the actual options, i.e.

```
.myListBox option {
    background-color: #FFFF00;
    color: #FF0000;
}
```

Though this will not work the same in all browsers. So you'll need to tweak for your own needs, or take a totally different approach like a 3rd party plug-in (look at jquery ui options) or building your own like Peri stated.

One option could be [jQuery UI Multiselect](http://www.quasipartikel.at/multiselect/), which you should can style with [Themeroller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/).

Although you may just want to play around with customizing your own / different approach to suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks... I updated this, although it was just a typo on Stack, not in my code :(

Comment: What jQuery element would I need to use?

Comment: Thanks... I got the look I wanted using JQuery... This answer is correct, although rendering in IE7 doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The exmaple site is not using listbox, they are just using html's unordered lists.
You probably can't achieve what they did with ASP.NET ListBox control. You would have to create your own control and make it render how you want.